Letters in \mathfrak appear displaced vertically
For me at least, the letters in $\mathfrak{su}$ appear vertically displaced — the "$\mathfrak{s}$" is lower than the "$\mathfrak{u}$". This happens only in the text body or in the list view, where the font is smaller, not in the title on the question page, where the font is larger. Is this a MathJax issue, or a problem with my browser?

I just checked on my Mac and Droid (both using Chrome), and both the Fraktur characters are on the same baseline.  However, they are actually both lower than the non-math text around them.

Which browser, on which operating system?

Does it look the same for every choice of math renderer?

Firefox on Linux (Ubuntu)

Firefox on Linux as well: in the default MathJax v2 setup, the $\mathfrak u$ indeed seems to be a bit above the baseline (with the HTML-CSS, Common HTML, and Preview HTML renderers). It displays correctly in MathJax v3.

It does indeed appear to depend on the Math renderer (HTML-CSS has the $\mathfrak{u}$ raised, Common HTML less so, MathML not at all [but then the horizontal spacing between the letters is too big]).
